# Connection refused between linked Docker containers in a custom network?

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose

I have the following case with Docker:

In a compose file I create a custom network the following way:

```
networks:
  my-docker-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.238.0/24
          gateway: 172.20.238.1
```

After that I create a couple of containers that are part of that network. They are linked and they both expose the same ports to the host (I don't want to publish the port, I just want to make it accessible from the host and the other container)

```
  web-backend-2:
    build: ./backend-web
    hostname: web-backend-host-2
    links:
      - web-backend-1
    expose:
      - 47500
    networks:
      my-docker-network:
        aliases:
          - backend2
    container_name: web-backend-2-service


  web-backend-1:
    build: ./backend-web
    hostname: web-backend-host-1
    expose:
      - 47500
    networks:
      my-docker-network:
        aliases:
          - backend1
    container_name: web-backend-1-service
```

The backend-web project is a simple centos7 container with a tomcat and some specific tomcat configurations. Now, when I compose the whole thing everything is just fine with one exception: I cannot connect from backend1 to backend2 (and vice-versa) on port 47500:

```
telnet backend1 47500
Trying 172.20.238.3...
telnet: connect to address 172.20.238.3: Connection refused
```

What's even more puzzling is that a telnet is successful on port 8080 without any EXPOSE declaration for it.

```
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
```

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide the dockerfile for your backend-web?

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding of how docker works:

you shouldn't expose ports that are needed for communication between containers that are on the same network ( in their "world" they should be able to talk to each other on any port without exposing it )

You should only expose ports to your host.

Make sure that you configured tomcat to run on 47500, i believe it is listening on 8080

you can go in the container with:

`docker exec -it <container name> bash`

`netstat -tulpn`

Comment: The thing is that the tomcat should run on 8080 (this is by default). 47500 port is used by the apache ignite nodes.
netstat showed nothing strange:

`...

tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      37/java

...

tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:47500         :::*                    LISTEN      37/java

...

`

Comment: i made a similar docker-compose file with 2 containers each running httpd on 80. i could telnet from one another with no problem, both exposed and not exposed. eg on web-backend-1-service `telnet backend2 80`. Therefore it is not a docker networking related problem. Make sure you didn't telnet to localhost.

Comment: I am not telnet-ing to localhost. I am starting to think that somewhere in the underlying containers there is something telling the docker engine to only expose 8080 for connections.